# IIR Filter - Finding Magnitude and Phase

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

I've been asked to plot the magnitude and phase response of this IIR filter.

$H(z)=\frac{0.0534(1+z^{-1})(1-1.0166z^{-1}+z^{-2})}{(1 - 0.683z^{-1})(1-1.4461z^{-1}+0.7957z^{-2})}$

And I've found a solution on the MatLab website which gives the following code:

```
b0 = 0.0534;
b1 = [1  1];
b2 = [1 -1.0166 1];
a1 = [1 -0.683];
a2 = [1 -1.4461 0.7957];

sos1 = [b0*[b1 0] [a1 0]];
sos2 = [b2 a2];

[h,w] = freqz([sos1;sos2],'whole',2001);

plot(w/pi,20*log10(abs(h)))
ax = gca;
ax.YLim = [-100 20];
ax.XTick = 0:.5:2;
xlabel('Normalized Frequency (\times\pi rad/sample)')
ylabel('Magnitude (dB)')
```

[image: Matlab website image]

Which when the magnitude isn't plotted in decibels looks like a bandstop. Is this due to aliasing as when I produce the graphs myself I get the result below.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the symmetry of the first plot, which you don't have in yours? In that case, it's just a result of the fact that the first plot is done all the way to the sampling frequency, while you only plot it until you reach the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: @DanielR Yes that was what I was referring to. Thanks for the explanation, I didn't realise that the freqz function with 'whole' did that. Thanks !!!

Comment: No problems, glad to help!

Comment: Do you know that there's a dsp.stackexchange.com site? Even though your problem is solved, you might want to post DSP related question on the dsp.SE site in the future. BTW, your filter is of course a lowpass filter.